# Click on submenu with jquery dopit did not open url

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with dopit plugin. I create a submenu and put this in custom.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav-drop').dropit();
});
```

This is result:
[image: Image of problem]

I type a links to user can change language, but when I click nothings happened. Can you help me?

Comment: because you have a `href="#"`.. where do you want to go?

Comment: link is below. In ul class "list nav-drop-menu", li childrens a tag. sorry for bad marker.